# Python bson library : get bson alias

Tags: python, mongodb, types, pymongo, bson

I am looking for a `type_of` method as below :

```
import bson
bson.type_of(42)  # it should return "int".
bson.type_of("hello")  # it should return "string".
type("hello").__name__   # it returns "str" and not "string" therefore no suitable.
```

The results I want ( `int` and `string`) are the BSON alias (see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/).

Does this method `type_of` already exist ?

It is okay if it returns the types' numbers ( 1 for Double, 2 for String ...).

Thank you,

Edit : 
Here is the solution I have for the moment:

```
type_of = {
    type(2.5).__name__: "number",
    type(1).__name__: "number",
    type("a_string").__name__: "string",
    type([1, 2]).__name__: "array",
    type(True).__name__: "bool"
}  # type_of[type(3).__name__] returns "number"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the actual BSON types (number is not a bson type) I'm not sure there is a way.  I've used this function to help sort out what python will encode the object as:

```
def what_bson_type(input):
    import bson
    return bson._ELEMENT_GETTER[bson.BSON.encode({"t":input})[4]].__name__[5:]
```

Note: these "types" do not match the bson spec, but they have been good enough to help me in the past.

```
>>> what_bson_type("hi")
'string'
>>> what_bson_type(1)
'int'
>>> what_bson_type(sys.maxint)
'int64'
>>> what_bson_type(True)
'boolean'
>>> what_bson_type({"a":"b"})
'object'
>>> what_bson_type(1.2)
'float'
>>> what_bson_type([1,2])
'array'
>>> what_bson_type(re.compile(r".*"))
'regex'
>>> what_bson_type(bson.Binary("hi"))
'binary'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, this types are not exactly the one I am looking for. However, I do look for a method from the bson library to help me.